# Issues when setting up Mobx with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm getting an error when setting up Mobx with react, can anyone give me a simple step by step? I'm fairly new to React and I'm still getting my head around the files that come with it.

**Here's what I did:**

- Used create-react-app
- ejected app
- Ran npm install --save mobx mobx-react
- ran npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators
- I then edited the package.json file:

  ```
     "babel": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"
      ],
      "presets": [
        "react-app"
      ]
    },
  ```

**Here's the problem I'm getting:** 
[image]

**What I tried:**

The error seems to suggest that I need to set legacy to true in node_modules\@babel\plugin-proposal-decorators\lib\index.js. I tried that and it didn't work. I searched for the problem on google and it seems like it could be an issue with Babel 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the option with the config you setup in your `package.json`

```
{
 "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

You can check the docs here: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators.html